# Listbox items delete

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listbox

How can I delete my listbox item text after Contains "?"  ?

Example listbox item text:

```
I want it ? please, remove it.
```

My code:

> ```
>         For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
>
>         If ListBox1.Items(i).ToString.StartsWith("?") Then
>         'something useful for me.
>         End If
>         Next
> ```

If I want to delete specific text then I use it.

```
For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            If CheckedListBox1.Items(i).ToString.Contains("something") Then
                CheckedListBox1.Items(i) = CheckedListBox1.Items(i).ToString.Replace("something", "")
            End If
```

But it's dynamically generated listbox items.
Example:

```
I want it ? please, remove it.1234
I want it ? please, remove it.2345
I want it ? please, remove it.64653
I want it ? remove461
etc...
```

Comment: ListBox1.Items.Remove or RemoveAt (i'm not sure )

Comment: **Your question is unclear** : Do you want **1)** to delete an item in your list box ? **2)** To replace an item in your listbox by another one ? or **3)** to replace/format/change/alter the displayed `TEXT` of an item in that listbox ?

Comment: 3. I want to replace(or delete) my listbox items text after "?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start looping backwards and then use [RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
For i = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If ListBox1.Items(i).ToString.StartsWith("?") Then
       ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next
```

When you want to remove one or more items from a collection is important to loop from the end of the collection towards its first element. If you loop in the normal forward mode you could have problems when you remove an item. For example, if you remove an item at position 5, the item at position 6 shifts in position 5 but then you increment the loop indexer to 6 effectively jumping your logic for the item that was previously at position 6

UPDATE: If you want to remove an item that contains the question mark then use a different method to check for the question mark existance in the examined item

```
For i = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If ListBox1.Items(i).ToString.Contains("?") Then
       ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
    End If
Next
```

Or, if you want to replace the current item that contains a question mark clipping away the text after the question mark write something like this

```
For i = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If ListBox1.Items(i).ToString.Contains("?") Then
       Dim item = ListBox1.Items(i).ToString()
       Dim pos = item.IndexOf("?"c)
       item = item.Substring(0, pos)
       ListBox1.Items(i) = item
    End If
Next
```

Eventually, if the question mark is surrounded by spaces you could add a TrimEnd

```
 item = item.Substring(0, pos).TrimEnd()
```

Comment: I updated my question, please read again. "ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)" is do nothing.

Comment: RemoveAt removes completely an item. Your condition (StartsWith) finds an item that starts with the question mark. If you want to remove item that Contains the question mark then you need to use Contains

Comment: Your code remove all items that contains "?", I want to replace(or delete) my listbox items text after "?"  Example:  I keep it?I delete it